# DATEADD in dd-MM-yyyy format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005, I am getting date from user in the format `dd-MM-yyyy` and limit of up to 5 days so user can see result upto +-5 days.

I tried a lot but unable to   :

1. Convert `dd-MM-yyyy` into `yyyy-MM-dd`
2. Add days to `dd-MM-yyyy` in a SQL query

My SQL query is:

```
 SELECT 
     (convert(varchar(10), OrderDate, 105)) AS OrderDate 
 FROM 
     [Products] p
 WHERE
     ((convert(varchar(10), OrderDate, 105)) BETWEEN
         (DATEADD(dd, -3, '22-01-2014'))
          AND
         (DATEADD(dd, 3, '22-01-2014'))
       )
```

In above query, suppose user enters `22-01-2014` as date and 3 as `flexibleDays` (so user can see result from 19-01-2014 to 25-01-2014).

How can I add days in format `dd-MM-yyyy` in above SQL query?

Comment: What datatype is `OrderDate` ?

Comment: @marc_s: its in DateTime format. 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' .

Comment: Is it **`DATETIME`** as datatype?? `DATETIME` has no string format associated with it....

Comment: @marc_s OrderDate's datatype is DateTime. User is entering 'dd-MM-yyyy', can I convert 'dd-MM-yyyy' to 'yyyy-MM-dd' or perform DATEADD function on 'dd-MM-yyyy' in any way?

Comment: You **cannot** add days to a string - it has to be a `DATE` or `DATETIME` - see my answer for a code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend **NOT** use overuse the date conversion to and from strings! If you convert a `DATE` or `DATETIME` to a string - of course you cannot add days to it - it's a string now after all!

So if you already **have** a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column - use it and leave it's datatype alone!

Try code something like this:

```
-- define inputs from user - a date in string format, and a number of days
DECLARE @UserEntered VARCHAR(20) = '22-01-2014'
DECLARE @FlexiDays INT = 3

-- declare some helper variables - user input as DATE, from and to dates
DECLARE @UserEnteredDate DATE 

DECLARE @FromDate DATE
DECLARE @ToDate DATE

-- determine the DATE the user entered, and the resulting "From" and "To" dates (as DATE)
SELECT @UserEnteredDate = CONVERT(DATE, @UserEntered, 105)

SET @FromDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1 * @FlexiDays, @UserEnteredDate)
SET @ToDate = DATEADD(DAY, @FlexiDays, @UserEnteredDate)

-- do your query without any messy conversions!
SELECT 
     OrderDate
FROM 
     [Products] p
WHERE
     OrderDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Comment: You made my day.... I tried this "CONVERT(DATE, @UserEntered, 105)" code into this "DATEADD(DAY,-2,CONVERT(DATETIME,'22-01-2014',105))" and its working fine, and Yup my code is messy a lot. will try implement your solution asap.

Comment: If the column is DATETIME, the OP may well want to compare only the DATE part, ignoring time of day (this is a common reason for converting to a date-only string format).  In which case, he probably wants something like "WHERE OrderDate >= @FromDate AND OrderDate < @ToDatePlusOne"

Comment: @marc_s - yes, casting would work on SQL Server 2008+, but the question is tagged with sql-server-2005.  And I'm not sure if casting would prevent the query plan from using any index there might be on the OrderDate column.  But in any case, comparing with a date range is of course better than converting to a string.

Comment: @Joe: ah darn - yes, SQL Server 2005 doesn't have `DATE` yet :-( But anyway: try to avoid casting to string, that's my main point!

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION SUBTRACT_DAYS( @date AS DATETIME, @days AS INT )
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
  RETURN DATEADD(dd, -@days, @date);
END

CREATE FUNCTION ADD_DAYS(@date AS DATETIME, @days AS INT )
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
  RETURN DATEADD(dd, +@days, @date);
END

SELECT dbo.SUBTRACT_DAYS('2014-01-22', 3),dbo.ADD_DAYS('2014-01-22', 3)
```

**OP**

```
Start                   End
2014-01-19 00:00:00.000 2014-01-25 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @UserEntered VARCHAR(20) = '22-01-2014'
DECLARE @FlexiDays INT = 3

DECLARE @UserEnteredDate DATE 

DECLARE @FromDate DATE
DECLARE @ToDate DATE

dates (as DATE)
SELECT @UserEnteredDate = CONVERT(DATE, @UserEntered, 105)

SET @FromDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1 * @FlexiDays, @UserEnteredDate)
SET @ToDate = DATEADD(DAY, @FlexiDays, @UserEnteredDate)
```